# Firebase Analytics vs Crashlytics vs GCF - Reporting exceptions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I am working on a React Native (Expo) app, where I have handled the different types of errors of my application using `try/catch` blocks and [Error Boundaries](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

My idea was to report the exceptions using [Craslytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics), but this tool is only available in the bare workflow, where different native modules are supported, and I am not planning to move there for now...

I have seen there is a [default event](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event), provided by Google Analytics, called `EXCEPTION`... could it be a good idea to track the errors via Firebase Analytics? I mean, is Firebase Analytics also used for error reporting?

My other idea was to implement my own *Cloud Function* to log the errors there... but I feel analytics is a better decision (because of the dashboard, the provided charts... and all the visual stuff).

What do you think?